# CSV data processed in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I want to read some data from a CSV file and create multiple canvases that contains the data from my CSV. I want each line of the CSV to have it's own canvas.
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>BaGr (Badge Generator)</title>
</head>


<body>
<h3>Create</h3>
<div id="output">
<script>

   const output = document.getElementById("output");
   let objects = [];
   function init() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
                //parsing objects, so reusable
                objects = generateObjects(this.responseText);
                //once objects are parsed generate view
                generateView();
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "test.txt", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    generateObjects = (responseText) => {
        const lines = responseText.split("\n");
        return lines.map(lineRaw=>{
             const line = lineRaw.split(',');
             if(line.length !== 4){
                console.warn("Line error.");
                return undefined;
             }

             return {name: line[0], surname: line[1], sex: line[2], role: line[3]};
        });
    }

    generateView = () => {
       output.innerHTML = objects.map(object=>generateCanvas(object).outerHTML).join("");
    }

    generateCanvas = (line) => {
       const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
       const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
       let pos = 230;
       for(let key in line){
          if(line.hasOwnProperty(key)){
             context.fillText(`${key.toUpperCase()}: `, 30, pos);
             context.fillText(line[key], 150, pos);
             pos += 20;
          }
       }
       return canvas;
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Still not working properly. When i click on inspect i see that the code has the canvases generated but they don't appear on my page.

Comment: This is what i have in the console

`(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:{name: "Popescu", surname: "Bogdan", sex: "masculin", role: "student
"}
1:{name: "Prelipcean", surname: "Radu", sex: "masculin", role: "avocat
"}
2:{name: "Antonie", surname: "Ioana", sex: "feminin", role: "profesor
"}
3:{name: "Arhire", surname: "Raluca", sex: "feminin", role: "asistenta
"}
4:{name: "Panaite", surname: "Alexandru", sex: "masculin", role: "contabil
"}
5:{name: "Bodnar", surname: "Ioana", sex: "feminin", role: "vizitator"}
length:6
__proto__:Array(0)`

Comment: `[{"name":"Popescu","surname":"Bogdan","sex":"masculin","role":"student\r"},{"name":"Prelipcean","surname":"Radu","sex":"masculin","role":"avocat\r"},{"name":"Antonie","surname":"Ioana","sex":"feminin","role":"profesor\r"},{"name":"Arhire","surname":"Raluca","sex":"feminin","role":"asistenta\r"},{"name":"Panaite","surname":"Alexandru","sex":"masculin","role":"contabil\r"},{"name":"Bodnar","surname":"Ioana","sex":"feminin","role":"vizitator"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version of what you're looking for. If you have any questions let me know.

```
const output = document.getElementById("output");
let objects = [];

function init() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //parsing objects, so reusable
      objects = generateObjects(this.responseText);
      //once objects are parsed generate view
      generateView();
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "test.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

generateObjects = (responseText) => {
  const lines = responseText.split("\n");
  return lines.map(lineRaw => {
    const line = lineRaw.split(',');
    if (line.length !== 4) {
      console.warn("Line error.");
      return undefined;
    }

    return {
      name: line[0],
      surname: line[1],
      sex: line[2],
      role: line[3]
    };
  });
}

generateView = () => {
  objects.forEach(object => generateCanvas(object))
}

generateCanvas = (line) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  output.appendChild(canvas);
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let pos = 50;
  for (let key in line) {
    if (line.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      context.fillText(`${key.toUpperCase()}:`, 30, pos);
      context.fillText(line[key], 150, pos);
      pos += 20;
    }
  }
}
```

### Working example with provided data

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");
let objects = [{
  "name": "Popescu",
  "surname": "Bogdan",
  "sex": "masculin",
  "role": "student\r"
}, {
  "name": "Prelipcean",
  "surname": "Radu",
  "sex": "masculin",
  "role": "avocat\r"
}, {
  "name": "Antonie",
  "surname": "Ioana",
  "sex": "feminin",
  "role": "profesor\r"
}, {
  "name": "Arhire",
  "surname": "Raluca",
  "sex": "feminin",
  "role": "asistenta\r"
}, {
  "name": "Panaite",
  "surname": "Alexandru",
  "sex": "masculin",
  "role": "contabil\r"
}, {
  "name": "Bodnar",
  "surname": "Ioana",
  "sex": "feminin",
  "role": "vizitator"
}];


generateView = () => {
  objects.forEach(object => generateCanvas(object))
}

generateCanvas = (line) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  output.appendChild(canvas);
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let pos = 50;
  for (let key in line) {
    if (line.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      context.fillText(`${key.toUpperCase()}:`, 30, pos);
      context.fillText(line[key], 150, pos);
      pos += 20;
    }
  }
}

generateView();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: yes it was working..i forget to add something to the code and that was why my console was empty..now i see the data on my console.

Comment: my CSV is like this

`Popescu,Bogdan,masculin,student
Prelipcean,Radu,masculin,avocat
Antonie,Ioana,feminin,profesor
Arhire,Raluca,feminin,asistenta
Panaite,Alexandru,masculin,contabil
Bodnar,Ioana,feminin,vizitator`

Comment: i get an error on this line: `output.innerHTML = objects.map(object=>generateCanvas(object).outerHTML).join("");`

the error is this:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at generateView (creare.html:36)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (creare.html:15)`

Comment: i added `const output = document.getElementById("output");` but it is still not working. that line should be at the very beginning of the code right?

Comment: i added the full code on a new comment so i can format it

Comment: yes sorry about that..i modified the code on my initial question so it is up to date.

Comment: i have one quick question. is there a method which will enable me to download all the canvases at once from my page? if you could direct me to somewhere where i can find an answer?

Comment: @MihaCraescu from the top of my mind, I am unsure if there is a method that exists. I'd say it's possible to create that method though, I'll take a look later when I get home.

Comment: thank you very much for all the help that you are giving me